# Sudo access fails

Tags: linux, sudo

When I try to execute sudo access from my account it fails with an error like

> suq46999 is not allowed to run sudo on vwc-1dnawap01

Server is configured in LDAP authentication

Users group is configured in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file

User is added to `/etc/sudoers` as such:

```
suq46999         ALL=(ALL)       ALL, !ADMIN_LIMIT
```

But still the user is not able to `sudo su - root`.

Comment: Check the definition of `ADMIN_LIMIT`, it probably contains `su`.